# How to create self referencing MongoDB schema and post routes using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am trying to create parent-child like nested system where child has same schema as of parent.Below is my parent schema, here children refers to the parentSchema again,

```
var mongoose    = require("mongoose");  
var parentSchema    =   new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
children:[
    {
        ref: this
    }
  ],
});

module.exports  =   mongoose.model("Parent", parentSchema);
```

Routes looks like this

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
Parent.find({}).populate("children").exec(function(err, allParents){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        res.render("index",{parents: allParents});
    }
});
});

app.post("/", function(req,res){
    var name    =   req.body.name;
    var desc    =   req.body.desc;
    var newParent = {name: name, description: desc}

Parent.create(newParent, function(err, newlyCreate){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        res.redirect("/");
    }
    });
});

app.post("/:id", function(req, res){
 Parent.findById(req.params.id, function(err, parent){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/");
    }else{
        parent.children.push(req.body.child);
        parent.save();
        console.log(parent.children);
        res.redirect("/");
    }
 });
});
```

The problem is when I send data from form to post route it prints it but after pushing it into parent.children and then printing parent.children is shows null. Where is the problem???
EJS page looks like below:-

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="desc" placeholder="Description">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class=btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
    <a href="/">Go Back</a>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="row">
<% parents.forEach(function(module){%>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item" style="margin-bottom: 5%;">
                <h2><%= module.name%></h2>
      <%= module.description %>
      <% console.log(module.children) %>
      <%module.children.forEach(function(node){%>
        <% console.log(node) %>
      <%});%>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div>
            <form action="/<%= module._id %>" method="POST">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="desc" placeholder="Description">
              </div>
                                <button>Submit</button>
                            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<% }); %>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell where is the problem in above code or can anyone suggest any other way to make this type of parent-child structure????

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `parent.save()` is asynchronus. Maybe you can try this instead.

```
parent.save().then(()=>{
  console.log(parent.children); 
  res.redirect("/");
});
```

or you can use async-await after putting `async` before function definition,

```
await parent.save();
console.log(parent.children);
res.redirect("/");
```

Please do write in comment if problem still persists.

Comment: I also think that's the problem.